# Does the sigma algebra of a random variable equal the sigma algebra generated by the pre-image of sets in a $\pi$-system?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ taking values in a measurable space $(M,\sigma(\mathcal{A}))$ where  $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system. Let $\sigma(X)$ the smallest sigma algebra such that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Does $\sigma(X):=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(\mathcal{E}):\mathcal{E}\in \sigma(\mathcal{A})\})=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(\mathcal{E}):\mathcal{E}\in \mathcal{A}\})$?

Comment: Yes, and even $\sigma \{X^{-1}(\mathcal E)\mid \mathcal E\in \sigma (\mathcal A)\}=\{X^{-1}(\mathcal E)\mid \mathcal E\in \sigma (\mathcal A)\}$. By the way, for your equality holds, no need that $\mathcal A$ be a $\pi-$system.

Comment: @Surb Do you have any reference for where this result is proved? Namely that $
\sigma(\{X^{-1}(\mathcal{E}):\mathcal{E}\in \sigma(\mathcal{A})\})=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(\mathcal{E}):\mathcal{E}\in \mathcal{A}\})
$